# How to convert text from one format to another?

Tags: format

I have a docx document which was removed and then restored but text in this file looks like this

```
$ÄjŸÕ˚ˆw‹~µ2ÑCpW'ø¥:©°»xa"º¥ ∫ÓŒV!‰áOc‘Nü·è?ÒQºrΩg¬~í¬;Æzã\k˝E…$ën"‡Íâ
```

Is there are anything i could do with it?
I guess i need to change format from something to something but i don't know how and where?
Would be very grateful for any advices.
I was trying to look but i can't even find name of this problem
And how do i know what format is that ?

Comment: This isn't really a Stack Overflow question; it's not about programming. Perhaps [su] might be able to help?

Comment: And it is obvious that the file is corrupted.  How can we answer what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

DOCX document are not plain text files !
You cannot just open open them an get the content. You have to open them up with a document editor that support docx files like Office Word or Libre Office Writer.

Comment: No i tried to open them but it opens ass notepad in mac os.
I need to atlest save the text

Comment: @Vlad If it doesn't open in LibreOffice Writer, you could open it in a zip archiving tool and manually extract the XML representation of the file. But it probably will open fine if you drag it onto LibreOffice Writer / Microsoft Word / Pages.

Comment: Unfortunately no.
I can only get this symbols 
¿í∫∑w:∑¶¥—<Å?ø‘ﬂñó~S±V
I need to just encode it from one format to another but what format is that i don't know.
I thought maybe there are some trick to find out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).